Azure Gstreamer error - basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3072: error: streaming stopped, reason error (-5)
We are using GStreamer in azure realtime speech to text, Actually Azure uses gstreamer internally to convert any audio format being streamed to their supported PCM format. When we deploy this websocket code in python and try connecting with it through our client.
The transcription is happening for around 8minutes 45seconds, After which this error pops up and suddenly the transcription stops.
Are there any setting that we should do from our side to avoid this, I'm also providing a screenshot of the error.
Error screenshot
Expected Behaviour
Transcribe the audio for as long as supported by Azure speech to text - 240mins
Code
import websockets
import asyncio
import uuid
import datetime
from app.utils.index import get_url_params
from app.service.api_service import verify_token
from app.service.logs_service import logger
from queue import Queue
from dataclasses import dataclass
import os
import json
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
from app.service.audio_processor_service import save_audio_file
from app.service.azure_speech_service import (
    create_conversation_transcriber,
)
import shutil
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

def generate_speech_config(self):
    try:
        speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(
            subscription=self.SPEECH_KEY,
            region=self.SERVICE_REGION,
        )
        speech_config.set_property(
            speechsdk.PropertyId.Speech_LogFilename,
            f"results/{self.connections['uuid']}/azure_speech_sdk.log",
        )
        speech_config.enable_audio_logging()
        speech_config.set_property(
            property_id=speechsdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_LanguageIdMode,
            value="Continuous",
        )
        speech_config.set_property_by_name("maxSpeakerCount", str(8))

        speech_config.request_word_level_timestamps()

        print("Speech config generated")
        return speech_config
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating speech config: {e}")


def create_conversation_transcriber(self):
    try:
        audio_stream_format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(
            compressed_stream_format=speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamContainerFormat.ANY
        )
        push_stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(
            stream_format=audio_stream_format
        )

        audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(stream=self.push_stream)

        speech_config = self.generate_speech_config()

        conversation_transcriber = speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber(
            speech_config=speech_config,
            audio_config=audio_config,
            auto_detect_source_language_config=speechsdk.AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig(
                languages=["en-US", "es-ES"]
            ),
        )

        conversation_transcriber.transcribing.connect(lambda evt: print(evt.result.text))
        conversation_transcriber.session_stopped.connect(lambda evt: print("Session stopped"))
        conversation_transcriber.canceled.connect(lambda evt: print("Canceled:", evt.reason))
        conversation_transcriber.transcribed.connect(lambda evt: print(evt.result.text))
        conversation_transcriber.session_started.connect(lambda evt: print("Session started"))

        print("Conversation Transcriber Initialized - azure_speech_service.py")

        return conversation_transcriber, push_stream

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in create_conversation_transcriber: {e}")



@dataclass
class CONNECTIONS:
    connections = {}


load_dotenv(find_dotenv())


async def send_transcribed_messages_async(uuid):
    try:

        while True:

            msg_queue = CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]["transcribed_queue"]
            while not msg_queue.empty():
                msg = msg_queue.get()
                websocket = CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]["websocket"]
                if websocket.open:
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
                    logger.info(f"Message sent to: {uuid}")
                else:
                    logger.warning("WebSocket is closed, unable to send message.")
                    break
            await asyncio.sleep(0.01)  # Prevent tight loop
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error sending transcribed message: {e}")


async def send_transcribing_messages_async(uuid):
    try:

        while True:

            msg_queue = CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]["transcribing_queue"]
            while not msg_queue.empty():
                msg = msg_queue.get()
                websocket = CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]["websocket"]
                if websocket.open:
                    await websocket.send(json.dumps(msg))
                    logger.info(f"Message sent to: {uuid}")
                else:
                    logger.warning("WebSocket is closed, unable to send message.")
                    break
            await asyncio.sleep(0.01)  # Prevent tight loop
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error sending transcribing message: {e}")


async def receive_audio(uuid, path):

    audio_queue = Queue(maxsize=0)

    try:

        conversation_transcriber, push_stream = create_conversation_transcriber(
            CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]
        )

        logger.info("Conversation transcriber initialized - socket_service.py")

        # Start continuous recognition
        conversation_transcriber.start_transcribing_async().get()

        while True:
            # Receive audio data from the WebSocket
            websocket = CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]["websocket"]
            data = await websocket.recv()

            if data:
                audio_queue.put_nowait(data)

                while not audio_queue.empty():
                    chunk = audio_queue.get()

                    CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]["audio_buffer"] += chunk
                    push_stream.write(chunk)

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
        logger.info("Connection closed")
        logger.info(e)
        conversation_transcriber.stop_transcribing_async().get()
        push_stream.close()

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in receive_audio: {e}")

    finally:

        conversation_transcriber.stop_transcribing_async().get()
        shutil.rmtree(f"results/{uuid}")


async def on_connect(websocket, path):

    logger.info(path)

    params_dict = get_url_params(path.split("/")[-1])

    token_id = params_dict["token"]
    encounter_id = params_dict["encounter_id"]

    try:
        resp = verify_token(token_id)
        res = resp.json()

        if resp.status_code == 200:
            logger.info("JWT Token verification successful")
        else:
            raise Exception(f"JWT Token verification failed - {resp.status_code}")

        UID = str(uuid.uuid4())

        os.makedirs("results", exist_ok=True)
        os.makedirs(f"results/{UID}", exist_ok=True)

        timestamp = f"{datetime.datetime.now()}".replace(":", "_").replace("-", "_")
        fname = f"{encounter_id}_{timestamp}"

        CONNECTIONS.connections[UID] = {
            "websocket": websocket,
            "transcribed_queue": Queue(maxsize=0),
            "transcribing_queue": Queue(maxsize=0),
            "filekey": f"{encounter_id}/{timestamp}",
            "fname": fname,
            "json_list": [],
            "audio_buffer": b"",
            "organizationId": res["organizationId"],
            "token": token_id,
            "encounter_id": encounter_id,
            "file_obj": open(f"results/{UID}/{fname}.txt", "w"),
            "log_files": ["Logs/azure_speech_sdk.log", "Logs/logfile.log"],
            "uuid": UID,
        }

        if res["organizationId"] is None:
            raise Exception("Organization ID not found")

        receive_audio_task = asyncio.create_task(receive_audio(UID, path))
        send_transcribed_messages_task = asyncio.create_task(
            send_transcribed_messages_async(UID)
        )
        send_transcribing_messages_task = asyncio.create_task(
            send_transcribing_messages_async(UID)
        )
        await asyncio.gather(
            receive_audio_task,
            send_transcribed_messages_task,
            send_transcribing_messages_task,
        )

    except Exception as e:
        logger.info(f"Error in on_connect - {e}")
        CONNECTIONS.connections.pop(UID)


async def run_websocket_server():
    start_server = websockets.serve(on_connect, "0.0.0.0", 8000, ping_interval=None)
    await start_server  # This will ensure the WebSocket server starts



Please share the code you tried  and error in text format.

I have added the code

The GStreamer error "streaming stopped" is an issue related to the audio input pipeline. The Azure Speech SDK uses GStreamer to handle audio processing and format conversion with the microphone/mav.
 audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename="sampledata_audiofiles_katiesteve.wav")
    conversation_transcriber = speechsdk.transcription.ConversationTranscriber(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)


Refer to this documentation for supported types in speech service .
alternative way:
audio_stream_format = speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamFormat(
            compressed_stream_format=speechsdk.audio.AudioStreamContainerFormat.ANY
        )
        push_stream = speechsdk.audio.PushAudioInputStream(
            stream_format=audio_stream_format
        )

with audio devices:
audio_config = AudioConfig(device_name="<device id>");

When the transcriber stops or fails, add the code below to automatically restart it after a delay.
async def receive_audio(uuid, path):
    audio_queue = Queue(maxsize=0)

    try:
        conversation_transcriber, push_stream = create_conversation_transcriber(
            CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]
        )

        logger.info("Conversation transcriber initialized - socket_service.py")
conversation_transcriber.start_transcribing_async().get()

        while True:
            websocket = CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]["websocket"]
            data = await websocket.recv()

            if data:
                audio_queue.put_nowait(data)

                while not audio_queue.empty():
                    chunk = audio_queue.get()

                    CONNECTIONS.connections[uuid]["audio_buffer"] += chunk
                    push_stream.write(chunk)

    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
        logger.info("WebSocket connection closed.")
        logger.info(e)
        # Attempt to restart the transcriber if the connection was unexpectedly closed
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        conversation_transcriber.start_transcribing_async().get()
        push_stream.close()

    except Exception as e:
   
        if "GStreamer error" in str(e) or "error (-5)" in str(e):
            logger.error(f"GStreamer error encountered: {e}")
   
            await asyncio.sleep(2)
            conversation_transcriber.start_transcribing_async().get()
        else:
            logger.error(f"Error in receive_audio: {e}")

    finally:
 conversation_transcriber.stop_transcribing_async().get()
        shutil.rmtree(f"results/{uuid}")



